# how replace distinct characters + number with another distinct characters in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to put <_c0> or <_c1>... in place of _b0 or _b1... in a long string,foe example my text is look like:hi my friend _b0,are you ok _b1 and _b2...,my try is:

`var u1 = item.text.replace(/_b/\d/g, '<b>'\d);`
tanx

Comment: So you got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags` error, have you tried fixing it?

Comment: this regular not work,this short code until show,what do i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`string.replace(/(_b\d)/g , "<$1>")`

```js
var text = "hi my friend _b0, are you ok _b1 and _b2...";
var u1 = text.replace(/(_b\d)/g , "<$1>");
console.log(u1);
```

Comment: if i want _b replace <_c>?

Comment: @miladdn131, if you want to replace `_b0` with `<_c0>` , then use `text.replace(/_b(\d)/g, '<_c$1>')`